# Vector to list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I´m trying convert a vector to multiple matrices and save them in a list.

```
#Create list to save matrix
BSEPRA=vector("list", 420)

#Vector size 6720
temporalRA
```

I need to build 4*4 size matrices with the first 16 elements then with the next ones (17:32) and so on up to 6705:6720 to have 420 and save them in the list.  But this doesn't work:

```
for (i in 1:length(temporalRA)){
temp2<-matrix(temporalRA[seq(1,6720, 16), ],nrow = 4,ncol = 4, )
BSEPRA[[i]]=temp2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
vec <- 1:32
split(vec, (seq_along(vec) - 1) %/% (4*4))
# $`0`
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
# $`1`
#  [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32

lapply(split(vec, (seq_along(vec) - 1) %/% 16), matrix, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
# $`0`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16
# $`1`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   17   21   25   29
# [2,]   18   22   26   30
# [3,]   19   23   27   31
# [4,]   20   24   28   32
```

If there's any concern that you will not have a perfect multiple of 16, I encourage you to take one extra step.

The problem:

```r
vec <- 1:30
vecs <- split(vec, (seq_along(vec) - 1) %/% (4*4))
vecs
# $`0`
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
# $`1`
#  [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

lapply(vecs, matrix, nrow = 4)
# Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   data length [14] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [4]
# $`0`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16
# $`1`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   17   21   25   29
# [2,]   18   22   26   30
# [3,]   19   23   27   17
# [4,]   20   24   28   18
```

(Notice how `17:18` are "recycled".)

The fix:

```r
vec <- 1:30
vecs <- split(vec, (seq_along(vec) - 1) %/% (4*4))
vecs <- lapply(vecs, `length<-`, max(lengths(vecs)))
vecs
# $`0`
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
# $`1`
#  [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 NA NA
lapply(vecs, matrix, nrow = 4)
# $`0`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16
# $`1`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   17   21   25   29
# [2,]   18   22   26   30
# [3,]   19   23   27   NA
# [4,]   20   24   28   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that I think will be more efficient than splitting the vector and iterating over the list to make matrices is to make an array and split it:

```
vec <- 1:32
mdim <- 4
mdimsq <- mdim^2

asplit(array(vec, dim = c(mdim, mdim, length(vec) / mdimsq)), 3)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   17   21   25   29
[2,]   18   22   26   30
[3,]   19   23   27   31
[4,]   20   24   28   32
```

Likewise, if the vector is not a perfect multiple it can be padded with NA:

```
vec <- 1:30
vln <- ceiling(length(vec)/mdimsq) * mdimsq
if (length(vec) < vln) vec[vln] <- NA 

asplit(array(vec, dim = c(mdim, mdim, length(vec) / mdimsq)), 3)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   17   21   25   29
[2,]   18   22   26   30
[3,]   19   23   27   NA
[4,]   20   24   28   NA
```